# Floating, Ord and RealFloat in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to figure out why this does not compile

```
yell :: (Floating a) => a -> [Char]
yell x
    | x > 10.0 = "Yelling"
    | otherwise = "No Yell"
```

but this

```
yell :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> [Char]
yell x
    | x > 10.0 = "Yelling"
    | otherwise = "No Yell"
```

and this

```
yell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> [Char]
yell x
    | x > 10.0 = "Yelling"
    | otherwise = "No Yell"
```

do compile.

I know that Floating and Ord are typeclasses, but isn't every member of Floating also a member of Ord? And in the end, is RealFloat just a "inner join" of Floating and Ord?

Comment: Floating point and equality are not exactly buddies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but isn't every member of `Floating` also a member of `Ord`?

The obvious counterexample are [complex numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex). Also, some types that give good `Num` etc. instances don't allow equality or inequality comparisons at all, because they represent more than just a single number value, but e.g. a generic abstraction over *function results of some number type*. (That's why `Eq` is not a superclass of `Num`, though it used to be.)

> in the end, is `RealFloat` just a "inner join" of `Floating` and `Ord`?

Pretty much, though `Real`, `RealFrac` and `RealFloat` actually contain a lot of very specific convenience methods – but I think you could implement them all (albeit much less efficiently) with just a `(Floating a, Ord a)` constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see definition of [`Floating`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating) typeclass. I think it's just defined as something that guarantees that the following functions can be used with it:

> pi, exp, log, sin, cos, asin, acos, atan, sinh, cosh, asinh, acosh, atanh

None of them requires its argument to be instance of `Ord`, so it's not. On the other hand [`Real`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Real) is an instance of `Ord` and so is `RealFloat`.